# Driver.quit() does not close browser

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver

Here's the code:

```
var number = 0;

function twentySeconds() {
    if (number <= 1) {
        loop();
        number++;
        console.log('Try number: ' + number);
    }
};

if (number > 2) {
    clearInterval(twentySeconds)
    console.log('Closing program!')
    driver.quit()
    return;

}

setInterval(twentySeconds, 20000);
```

So I am creating one Firefox instance and then I use it to search multiple times for a website. After it tries for a number of times, the program should stop (in this case, after the third try, the program should stop).
The problem is that at the end (when it ends the third check) driver.quit() shall close the browser and end the execution of the code. Instead, it just freezes, without ever closing the browser and ending the program.

What is the problem caused by? Do I need to open a tab for every search I do?

For the full view of the code please go to https://github.com/PrinceMatthew/bitcoinProjects/blob/master/improved_address_verifier.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to replace the second `if` with `else` and that's it, after following the indications given by Titus.

Result:

```
var number = 0;
var intervalId = setInterval(twentySeconds, 20000);

function twentySeconds() {
    if (number <= 1) { //(number <= x), where x is the number of times the program should execute - 1
        loop();
        number++;
        console.log('Try number: ' + number);
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(intervalId)
        console.log('Closing program!')
        driver.quit(); //close browser and quit program
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in the body of the `if` statement (the one outside the `twentySeconds` function) will never be executed because `number` is always `0` when the condition (`number > 2`) is evaluated. You should move that if statement inside the `twentySeconds` function.

Beside this, `clearInterval(twentySeconds)` won't work because `twentySeconds` is a function and the first parameter to `clearInterval` should be the interval's ID (the value returned by `setInterval(..)`).

Try this:

```
var number = 0;
var intervalId = setInterval(twentySeconds, 20000);

function twentySeconds() {
  if (number <= 1) {
    loop();
    number++;
    console.log('Try number: ' + number);
  }
  if (number > 2) {
    clearInterval(intervalId)
    console.log('Closing program!')
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Titus, but there is no change. After the second try, it just freezes, without closing the browser or retrying.